# Webclient results with default parameter value

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-scraping, webclient

I am trying to parse a webpage through web client using following code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lnk As String = "http://www.therapy-directory.org.uk/search.php?search=Central+London&distance=100&uqs=717425"
    Dim wb As New WebClient()
    wb.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    AddHandler wb.DownloadStringCompleted, AddressOf getTotal
    wb.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri(lnk))
End Sub

Private Sub getTotal(sender As Object, e As DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs)
    If e.Error Is Nothing Then
        Dim str As String = e.Result
        Dim doc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
        doc.LoadHtml(str)

        On Error Resume Next
        Dim tot As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@id,'search-results')]//h3[contains(@class,'search-title')]")(0) '("//div[contains(@id,'search-results')]//span[contains(@class,'pcolour')]")(0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not tot Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox(tot.InnerText)
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox(e.Error.Message)
    End If
End Sub
```

The result I got from this code is "380 results within 6 miles"..But,I have set parameter value of 100 for mile. I can view in the webbrowser there are around 1600 within 100 miles.

It seems, it showing value with its default value for Miles